# ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: lexical error: invalid char in json text

Tags: ijson

*hi all ijson newbie I have a very large .json file 168 (GB) I want to get all possible keys, but in the file some values are written as NaN. ijson creates a generator and outputs dictionaries, in My code value. When a specific item is returned, it throws an error. How can you get a string instead of a dictionary instead of value? Tried* **parser = ijson.items (input_file, '', multiple_values = True, map_type = str) **, *didn't help.*

```
def parse_json(json_filename):
    with open('max_data_error.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        with open(json_filename, 'r') as input_file:'''


            # outfile.write('[ '
            parser = ijson.items(input_file, '', multiple_values=True)
            cont = 0
            max_keys_list = list()
            for value in parser:
                for i in json.loads(json.dumps(value, ensure_ascii=False, default=str)) :
                    if i not in max_keys_list:
                        max_keys_list.append(i)
                        print(value)
                        print(max_keys_list)

            for keys_item in max_keys_list:
                outfile.write(keys_item + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_json('./email/emailrecords.bson.json')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "panda read.py", line 29, in <module>
    parse_json('./email/emailrecords.bson.json')
  File "panda read.py", line 17, in parse_json
    for value in parser:
ijson.common.IncompleteJSONError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
          litecashwire.com","lastname":NaN,"firstname":"Mia","zip":"87
                     (right here) ------^
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file I not valid JSON (`NaN` is not a valid JSON value); therefore any JSON parsing library will complain about this, one way or another, unless they have an extension to handle this non-standard content.

The ijson FAQ found in the project description has a question about invalid UTF-8 characters and how to deal with them. Those same answers apply here, so I would suggest you go and try one of those.